# How to use spesific variable value in different host of the same group in Ansible Playbook?

Tags: ansible

i have a group with multiple hosts (A,B) and few tasks that will run each 1 time in every hosts of the group.

```
- hosts: myhost
  vars:
    - var1: "{{ lookup('vars', TEMPLATE).source }}"

  #var1 contain 4 value: test1, test2, test3, test4

  tasks:
    - name: load var1
      include_vars:
        dir: "./var"
        files_matching: "var.yaml"

    - name: copy this file template
      copy:
        src: "./file"
        dest: "tmp/"
#file is a template contain "variable={{ var 1 }}"
```

i need to copy multiple file that contain ODD value to host A and multiple file that contain EVEN value to host B
for example:

in host A file1 with content "variable=test1" and file2 with content "variable=test2" will be created and
in host A file1 with content "variable=test3" and file2 with content "variable=test4" will be created

How to achive this?

ADDITION:

var1 contain 4 value: [test1, test2, test3, test4]

ODD : test1, test3

EVEN: test2, test4

the template file:

variable:{{ var1 }}

what i want:

generate file1 in host A contain:

variable: test1

generate file3 in host A contain:

variable: test3

generate file2 in host B contain:

variable: test2

generate file4 in host B contain:

variable: test4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i have understood what you want:

```
- hosts: myhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    - var1: ["test1","test2","test3",test4"]

  tasks:
  - name: Creating a file with content
    copy:
      dest: "file{{ idx }}"
      content: "variable:{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ var1 }}"
    vars:
      idx: "{{ item | regex_replace('[^0-9]','')}}"
      even: "{{ idx | int is even }}"
    when: (inventory_hostname == 'A' and not even) or (inventory_hostname == 'B' and even)
```